# What GUIs are there for making a custom Ubuntu distro?

Tags: gui, custom-distributions

I already tried getting Ubuntu Builder and Remastersys, but the file hosts for them seem to be shut down.  Are there any other GUIs for making a distro?

Comment: Not one that has ever worked well or been supported for long. By far the easiest are the Debian live scripts

Answer (score 0):

Not any more…

It's pretty much *all command-line stuff* nowadays as per the [official Ubuntu customisation documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomization)…

*Sorry to be the harbinger of bad news…*

Comment: As you're a reputation 1 user: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means [Yes, this answer is valid](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)!  **;-)**